# How i can send android app calculated text to UWP (C#) application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windowsiot

i want to send my android app calculated text to my UWP application.
Please tell me how i can do that, thanks

Suppose my app id addition app, and i add two numbers and resultant will my text which i want to transfer to UWP application.

Comment: app text? do you mean app code?

Comment: no no, =D , Suppose i have addition app then result of addition is my app text actually =D.

Comment: How do you want to transfer the data from one app to other? Bluetooth? Wi-Fi? I don't really think if it's possible out of the box. Maybe you'll need some extra tools like email or text file to transfer data and then read the file in other app.
This is because they are two different operating systems and you cant open both apps in one operating system if you wanted to directly send data. You'll need a remote server to send data from one app to the other.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, i want to connect my windows IOT app to android phone using Bluetooth

Comment: I have no prior knowledge of Windows IoT, maybe someone else cane help you.

Comment: [This](https://www.hackster.io/patricia2/bluetooth-remote-control-android-for-windows-iot-devices-ed502d) maybe helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with project rome.  You'd use the SDK on both android and UWP.  The draw back using project Rome instead of building your own server side is that project Rome requires your users to sign in with a Microsoft account